# Cordova gradle installed but not found

Tags: android, windows, cordova, gradle

I'm trying to get an environment for android and cordova, but I don't know why cordova doesn't link with gradle.

I've tried to re install gradle for command line, then tried to get it from npm but whatever i do, the "cordova requirements" command tells me that gradle is not installed.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem !
I changed "path" (https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) and added the path to my gradle's binary file : C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case I did downgrade gradle and Cordova to be able to work.